# Print match and line after

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have some data where the 4th column will either be `frz` or `-`.  I would like to find all lines where the 4th column is `frz` only if the 4th column on the next line is `-` and then print both lines.

Sample input:

```
2018-04-09T14:15:23.366Z  7 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 uuid3 -
2018-04-09T14:15:23.978Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 -        -
2018-04-09T14:29:35.826Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T00:35:54.338Z  9 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 -        -
2018-06-28T00:47:51.679Z  9 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 uuid3 -
2018-06-28T00:47:51.720Z 10 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 -        -
2018-06-28T00:47:58.863Z 10 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
```

Expected output:

```
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
```

---

I've found a few `awk` commands to print the line after a match but I can't figure out how to match both lines and print both.

What I currently have:

```
$ awk 'f{print;f=0} $4=="frz"{f=1}' input
2018-04-09T14:29:35.826Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
awk '$4=="-" && prev4=="frz" {print prevline; print} {prev4 = $4; prevline=$0}' file
```

Comment: ty sir, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU grep and your pattern doesn't occur elsewhere in the data, you can try this :

```
grep -A1 frz | grep -vB1 frz
```

## Explanation

The first `grep` captures all lines where the pattern occurs, plus the next one :

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>   Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.

The output of this first command on your sample input is :

```
2018-04-09T14:15:23.978Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 -        -
2018-04-09T14:29:35.826Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
--
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
```

Then the second command searches for lines *not* containing the pattern, and prints them with the line before :

> -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>   Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.

As noted in the [grep man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), the ouput contains group separators (`--`) :

```
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
--
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
```

You can add a third `grep` to remove them if needed :

```
grep -A1 frz | grep -vB1 frz | grep -v '^--$'
```

Comment: Nice. The regular expressions can be made such that "frz" is taken in the 4th column, but the bones of the solution are strong.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to offer a completely impractical GNU `grep` approach.  Works, but looks nasty.

```
grep -Pzo "^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+frz\s+.*\n\S+\s+\S+\s\S+\s+\-\s+.*" input
```

Example.

```
$ cat file
2018-04-09T14:15:23.366Z  7 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 uuid3 -
2018-04-09T14:15:23.978Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 -        -
2018-04-09T14:29:35.826Z  8 multi frz   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T00:35:54.338Z  9 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 -        -
2018-06-28T00:47:51.679Z  9 multi -   uuid1 uuid2 uuid3 -
2018-06-28T00:47:51.720Z 10 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 -        -
2018-06-28T00:47:58.863Z 10 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
$ grep -Pzo "^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+frz\s+.*\n\S+\s+\S+\s\S+\s+\-\s+.*" file
2018-04-09T17:19:01.901Z  8 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-03T22:12:38.688Z  8 multi -   uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T16:29:01.624Z 10 multi frz uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
2018-06-28T17:29:01.624Z 10 multi - uuid1 uuid3 uuid2 -
$ grep -V 2>&1|head -1
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
$
```

Comment: I get `grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz` with this. grep version "grep (GNU grep) 2.25" -- I think you need to replace `^` with `\n`

Comment: Interesting.  v2.20 here, which doesn't have that trouble.  Replacing `^` with `\n` no good on v2.20, results in an unwanted empty line prior to each match.

Comment: I can see on the [NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/NEWS?h=v2.25) file in the grep git repo that they were changing things related to this in versions 2.24 and 2.25

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed too

```
sed -E '
  /([^ ]* *){3}frz .*/!d
  $!N
  /(.*\n)([^ ]* *){3}- .*/!D
' infile
```

Comment: Constrain the `N` to operate on not last lines, `$!N` OTW, a last line ending with "frz" in it's 3rd field would get printed too.

Comment: @RakeshSharma You are right thanks update the answer

Comment: The first regex is in need of an overhaul, for as things stand now, it will match a line with  "frz" in 4th field when   it doesn't find in the 3rd but in 4th. You need to ⚓ it to the beginning of pattern space. The .* is superfluous in both the regexes.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Sorry but I don't understand exactly what you want to say. Yes my answer is not perfect and it's always imaginable to find a way where it fail. If you have a better solution, you can post a answer.